# JavaScript behaviours don't run on first page load after clearing cache

Tags: 7, javascript

Refresh the page again, however, and all behaviours function as they should. Why?

```
(function ($) {

console.log('This console.log runs');

Drupal.behaviors.endlessUniform = {
    attach: function (context) {

        console.log('This console.log does not run');

        $(function () {
            $("select").uniform();
        });
    }
}
})(jQuery);
```

My JS file runs the first time the page is loaded after flushing the cache, however, anything inside a drupal behaviour does not. Refresh the page and load it a second time after flushing the cache and the behaviours function as expected.

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers :) There's not enough information here to answer this, currently anything resembling an answer would have to be a straight-up guess based on a bunch of unknown factors - such questions aren't suitable for the strict Q+A format here. Please provide relevant portions of the offending code, details of error messages, and any other information that's going to help to make this into a _specific_, useful question for future visitors. Once you've had a chance please flag for re-opening. There's more info about the site and what types of questions to ask in the [help]. Thanks

Comment: Is that enough information?

Comment: Enough to get going, sure - you'll almost certainly have errors in your browser console; I'd suspect either 404s related to missing JS files that contain your code, maybe 404s for core files, but you should have at least a few errors in there ("jQuery is not defined" is a common one). Take a look and edit those into the question (or at least confirm that you see no errors), that'll help to narrow it down

Comment: Turns out the admin menu module was using a deprecated jQuery function, browser detection. This was causing the error, the module had an update released two weeks ago that solves the problem!

Comment: Ah, `msie is undefined` by any chance? ;) I've been on the dev version of admin menu for about 2 years to get around that!

Comment: Exactly that! Looking into the update release code, it's been scrapped altogether which is good.